# C# namespace questions

Tags: c#

what's the difference for the following two ways to define namespace?

```
namespace A.B.C {
     public class AA{

    }
}

namespace A {
    namespace B{
        namesapce C{
            public class AA{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

in some where I may have

```
namespace A{
//some classes 
}

namespace A.B {
//some classes
}

namespace A {
namespace B {
 //some classes
}
}
```

Both need to do the same to use class AA by `using A.B.C;` Can I use `C.AA a;` to specify the AA class in C namespace or I have to use the fall namespace convention: `A.B.C.AA a;` to avoid possbile confliction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're the same. If you look at this code in [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
namespace A {
namespace B{
namespace C{
public class AA{

}
}
}
}
```

you get this:

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    public class AA
    {
        // Methods
        public AA();
    }
}
```

Both methods are compiled to exactly the same intermediate language code.

Comment: What about the other question "Can I use C.AA a; to specify the AA class in C namespace or I have to use the fall namespace convention: A.B.C.AA a; to avoid possbile confliction?". As far as I know you can achieve this only by using alias (using C = A.B.C).